# formValidation.io doesn't work after load form via jquery post

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap-3, formvalidation.io

I've got some problems with my code. Basically I have the following issue:

**JS**

```
function {
    $.post( "form.php",function( data ) {
        $("#div_element").html( data );
    } );
}

$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#mybtn').on('click', function() {
        $('#myform').bootstrapValidator('validate');
    });
});


$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#myform').bootstrapValidator({
        framework: 'bootstrap',
        excluded: [':disabled', ':hidden', ':not(:visible)'],
        icon: {
            valid: 'glyphicon glyphicon-ok',
            invalid: 'glyphicon glyphicon-remove',
            validating: 'glyphicon glyphicon-refresh'
        },
        fields: {
            subject: {
                validators: {
                    notEmpty: {
                        subject: 'This field is required'
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    })

    .on('success.form.bv', function(e) {
        //do something
    });
});
```

**PHP**   (form.php)

```
<form id="myform">
<div class="form-group">
<label class="col-sm-2 control-label">Subject</label>
<div class="col-sm-3">
    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="subject" id="subject">
</div>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
<div class="col-sm-2 col-sm-offset-2">
    <button type="button" id="mybtn" class="btn btn-default">Send</button>
</div>
</div>
```

**HTML**

```
<div id="div_element"> 

</div>
```

OK, the thing is after load the form via ajax in my html code the button doesn't validate the form on click, so, I've been looking everywhere and I've found something related to delegation, but unfortunately without success.

For example:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#div_element').on('click','#mybtn', function() {
        $('#myform').bootstrapValidator('validate');
    }); 
});
```

So, Does anybody knows how to validate a *form* after *loading* like a *new content* in a HTML code via jquery post with *formvalidatio.io plugin*?

Thank you.

Comment: What is the purpose of the first JS function?

Comment: Well... when I clicked a button in a nav-bar (Bootstrap), I wanna load a form (first JS function) to send some data to my server MYSQL, the thing is the button inside the php file doesn't work after loaded via jquery post with formvalidation.io plugin.

Comment: I've been trying to do everything with ajax in order to avoid jump into another page to do something that I can do via ajax in the same page.

Comment: did you get this to work? I'm also trying to get an imported form to work with ajax call. using https://formvalidation.io/

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue, came here and was bummed there was no answer. After a few hours of trying, I sorted it out.

Using AJAX (via axios) I insert the form and JS on the page using:

```
$("#content_area").html(response.data);
```

In order to get the JS to see the new form, I eventually sorted out I need to wait for the DOM to be updated.  Can't use the document.ready, since the document is ready. Couldn't use a DOM loaded command, as the DOM is loaded. Eventually, I ended up using a defer function to make it work.

```
function defer(method) {
    if (window.jQuery) {
        method();
    } else {
        setTimeout(function() { defer(method) }, 50);
    }
}
```

And then the formvalidator code:

```
defer(function () {
    $('#my_form').formValidation({
        ...
    })
})
```

This allowed the DOM to completely load and the formValidation to find it and, then, work.